# SSRS - Can we create border with text in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, border

Instead of solid line border, can we create border with text in SSRS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not directly. There are some ways you could simulate that behavior though. One option is to use a pre-made background image. Another option would be to have rectangles around the border that repeat an image with the word. So you'll have to get creative with it.

Comment: Thanks Steve. 
We have thought of two options
1 - As mentioned by you, Rectangles around the border that repeat an image with the word
2 - Rectangles around the border directly with the repeating word within
Let's see which works better.